# Thyristor turn off time in circuit with RL load?

Tags: resistors, ac, thyristor

For circuits like this where the src is turned on, and should turn off in beta as shown in the second image.

What happens when the diode doesnt conduct after pi, when the voltage is negative, will the src turn off when the diode stops conducting ?

[image: SRC]

[image: alfa and beta picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCR stands for Silicon Controlled Rectifier, while the diode is just a Silicon Rectifier. Both devices would behave in same manner, what you get is just a additional voltage drop on diode, but nothing else.

You can search for half wave rectifier with inductive load and you will see that it's almost the same, except that with SCR you can also control the conduction angle. Combining SCR and diode in series would give the same.